# Call to undefined method App\Models\Car::setCreatedAt() - Laravel - 5.8.16

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am using latest Laravel. I have a model `Car` - `id | name | * timestamp columns`:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
}
```

Cars migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('name')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I am trying to save new row in `cars` table in the controller:

```
    $car = new Car();
    $car->name = 'example';
    $car->save();
```

, but for `$car->save()`, I am getting this error:

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Car::setCreatedAt()

Even, If I create new migration/model `create_table_test` (table with the same columns), I am getting the same error.

EDIT with stacktrace:

> 65 BadMethodCallException in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:50
>
> 64 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:throwBadMethodCallException in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:36
>
> 63 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:forwardCallTo in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1614
>
> 62 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:__call in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasTimestamps.php:47
>
> 61 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:updateTimestamps in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:791
>
> 60 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:performInsert in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:663
>
> 59 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:save in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/CarsController.php:33
>
> 58 App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CarsController:importCars/mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
>
> 57 call_user_func_array in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php:54
>
> 56 Illuminate\Routing\Controller:callAction in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php:45
>
> 55 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:dispatch in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:219
>
> 54 Illuminate\Routing\Route:runController in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:176
>
> 53 Illuminate\Routing\Route:run in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:680
>
> 52 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
>
> 51 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-stack-middleware/src/ClosureHttpKernel.php:30
>
> 50 Barryvdh\StackMiddleware\ClosureHttpKernel:handle in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/helthe/turbolinks/StackTurbolinks.php:51
>
> 49 Helthe\Component\Turbolinks\StackTurbolinks:handle in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-stack-middleware/src/ClosureMiddleware.php:36
>
> 48 Barryvdh\StackMiddleware\ClosureMiddleware:handle in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
>
> 47 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline{closure} in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>
> 46 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41
>
> 45 Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings:handle in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
>
> 44 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline{closure} in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>
> 43 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php:43
>
> 42 Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate:handle in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
>
> 41 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline{closure} in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>
> 40 Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline:Illuminate\Routing{closure} in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:75
>
> 39 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken:handle in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
>
> 38 Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline:Illuminate\Pipeline{closure} in /mnt/e/xampp/htdocs/room2/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
>   ......

Comment: Please post the stacktrace. Is that the whole `Car` model?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question. Yes, this is all about the model `Car`.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? The stacktrace doesn't match the `laravel-5.2` tag.

Comment: Laravel: `5.8.16`

Comment: Take a look at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasTimestamps.php`: Is there no `setCreatedAt()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I just re-install `Laravel`.

1. Delete `vendor` folder ;
2. Delete `composer.lock`;
3. `composer update` in the console.

Thanks, @Jonas Staudenmeir for your help.